# How to pass MultipartFile param in JUNIT testing?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit

I want to upload a multipartfile. When I use my REST request everything works just fine. When I want to test in JUnit the multipartfile param is not transmitted, I think (because I can't reach the main breakpoint in the debugger).

Error log:

> Expected MultipartHttpServletRequest: is a MultipartResolver configured?

**spring-common-test.xml**:

```
    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
       <!-- max upload size in bytes -->
       <property name="maxUploadSize" value="20971520" /> <!-- 20MB -->

       <!-- max size of file in memory (in bytes) -->
       <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="1048576" /> <!-- 1MB -->
    </bean>
```

**Controller**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/services/tasks/addDocument",  method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
 @ResponseBody
    public String set(@RequestParam("idTask") Long idTask,@RequestParam("descriere") String descriere,@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
       //things}
```

**Test**

```
 @Test
 public void testAddDocController() throws Exception {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:/HaxLogs.txt");
    MockMultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("file", fis);

    HashMap<String, String> contentTypeParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
    contentTypeParams.put("boundary", "265001916915724");
    MediaType mediaType = new MediaType("multipart", "form-data", contentTypeParams);

    String resp = mockMvc.perform(post("/services/tasks/addDocument").param("idTask", "141").param("descriere","vadfadfad").param("name", "C:/HaxLogs.txt").content(multipartFile.getBytes()).contentType(mediaType))
            .andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
    //.andExpect(status().isOk());
    System.out.println(resp);
}
```

Comment: @kryger thanks for the edit

Comment: How are you loading your test context that specifics your `CommonsMultipartResolver`?